# How to set up page structure correctly

Tags: html, mysqli, php

I am having trouble displaying the right details after a submit. I think my page structure is incorrect What is happening at moment is that if I click on the `Module` Submit button, nothing is being displayed which is incorrect.

Below is what is suppose to happen: (The page works in 3 parts)

**Part 1:** Contains a module drop down menu. User selects option from drop down menu and submits. Everytime it is submitted, it changes part 2 and part 3 is hidden. After submission drop down menu goes back to Please Select option.

**Part 2:** Contains Assessment drop down menu, only appears after user has submitted part 1. When this part is submitted by user selecting option from Assessment drop down menu and clicking on submit button, drop down menu goes back to Please Select and part 3 appears. Part 3 changes everytime part 2 is submitted with different options.

**Part 3:** Display details from part 2. Only appears and changes depending on Assessment chosen and submitted from part 2. If user submits from part 1, then this part is hidden.

Now my attempt is to seperate the php and phmtl from each other but like I said he problem is that no details is being displayed. Bear with me there is a lot of code but that is because I need to showw how my page is structured. My question is what things do I need to do in order to fix the page structure?

You can see what is happening with the application here: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/InputTest.php)

Below is the code which goes in the order it is displayed in: (I tried to limit down as much as I can):

**PHP:**

```
         <?php

// connect to the database

$moduleactive = 1;

$sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo";


//excute query

$sqlnum = $sqlstmt->num_rows();

$moduleHTML = "";
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

while ($sqlstmt->fetch()) {
    $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
}

$moduleHTML .= '</select>';

$pHTML = "";

//Module Submit (Part 1 Submitted)    
if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {
    $sessionquery = " 
SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId, SessionActive, Complete 
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId 
WHERE 
(ModuleId = ? AND SessionActive = ? AND Complete = ?) 
ORDER BY SessionName  
";

    $active   = 1;
    $complete = 1;

    //execute query 

    $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();

    $sessionHTML = '';

    if ($sessionnum == 0) {
        $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>";
    }

    $sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
    $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;

    while ($sessionqrystmt->fetch()) {
        $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i", strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
    }


    $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

}

//Session Submit (Part 2 Submitted)

if (isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) {
    $sessiondetailsquery = " 
    SELECT SessionId, SessionName 
    FROM Session 
    WHERE 
    (SessionId = ?) 
";

    //execute query

    $sessiondetailsqrystmt->bind_result($detailsSessionId, $detailsSessionName);

}

?>
```

**PHTML:**

```
 <form action="<?php
    echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    ?>" method="post"> 
    <table> 
    <tr> 
    <th>Module: <?php
    echo $moduleHTML;
    ?></th> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 
    <p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p> 


      <?php
    if ($step == 2) {
        if (!$_POST['moduleSubmit']) {
            if ($_POST['modules'] == '') {
    ?>  
               <span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>  
           <?php
            } elseif (!$sqlnum) {
    ?>  
               <span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>  
            <?php
            } else {
    ?>  
        <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
        <p><input id='sessionSubmit' type='submit' value='View Assessment Details' name='sessionSubmit' /></p>  
         <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?> 

      <?php
    if ($step == 3) {
        if (!$_POST['sessionSubmit']) {
            if ($_POST['session'] == '') {
    ?>  
               <span style='color: red'>Please Select an Assessment</span>  
            <?php
            } else {
    ?>   

    <table> 
    <tr> 
    <td></td> 
    <td><input type='text' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='$detailsSessionId' /></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td><strong>Assessment:</strong></td> 
    <td>{$detailsSessionName}</td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 
         <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?> 

    </form> 

        </body> 
    </html>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: modules in ...on line 66
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ... on line 68 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ... on line 69
Notice: Undefined index: modules in ... on line 116
```

PHP fiddle updated: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cbx-6mi

Comment: Please keep your browser's console open when testing your code. You'll see that you get a helpful error. `ReferenceError: getButtons is not defined`

Comment: @RuchitRami: So +1 for making the question absolutely useless if those links ever break? It's super that you like jsFiddle, but StackOverflow shouldn't have dependencies.

Comment: @user1689607 I am not getting a reference error at all in my browser error console. I am receiving no errors at all. Anyway I include the getButtons() function in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjqr6/41/). I have no errors but still same problem

Comment: Well you would  have needed to follow the steps you laid out in the question to see the error. When you tried to call the non-existent `getButtons()`, the error showed.

Comment: @user1689607: it is not just because addition of jsfiddle, it is for the effort put in to make those jsfiddle so that someone like you and me can understand easily. And in javascript questions, jsfiddle are most helpful which are not available in SO.

Comment: All these comments looks funny now :) While practice of rewriting old messages does not.

Comment: You use `$step` in your PHTML but where is this set? It doesn't appear in the PHP you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about how you want the structure to be, but from what i could understand this is the answer to your question.

You should see the structure, and hopefully you can use it =)

The idea is to show a section depending on how much info the user have given us.

And also allow the user to go back and change old data.

I have commented out some of your "code", and added some options that you should remove. But this things should show you the structure suggested without you being forced to input your code.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <th>
                <?php
                    // connect to the database
                    //$sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo";
                    //excute query
                    //$sqlnum = $sqlstmt->num_rows();
                ?>
                Module: 
                <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <?php
                        /*
                        while ($sqlstmt->fetch()) {
                            echo sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s_%3$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName, $dbModuleId);
                        }
                        */
                    ?>
                    <option value="test">test</option>
                </select>
            </th> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
    <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["module"]))
{
?>
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="$_POST[module]">
    Assigments: 
    <?php
        $sessionquery = "SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId, SessionActive, Complete 
        FROM Session s 
        INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId 
        WHERE 
        (ModuleId = ? AND SessionActive = ? AND Complete = ?) 
        ORDER BY SessionName";

        //execute query 

        //$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();

        if ($sessionnum == 0 && false) // "&& false" should ofcourse be removed
        {
        ?>
    <span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
    <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <?php
            /*
            while ($sessionqrystmt->fetch()) {
                $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dbSessionDate)), date("H:i", strtotime($dbSessionTime))) . PHP_EOL;
            }
            */
            echo "<option value='tst'>tst</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Assigments">
</form>
<br>
<br>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["session"]))
    {
        ?>
            <table> 
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td><input type='text' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='$detailsSessionId' /></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><strong>Assessment:</strong></td> 
                    <td>{$detailsSessionName}</td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you only want one "step" to be shown at the time, use "else if" instead of "if" (of course it need a little more than that, but you should understand how to do it from that?)

Comment: and it should be mentioned that this should be in a php file?

Comment: Hi, You see the issue I have now is the user submits part 1, it shows part 2, that is fine, but when I submit part 2, instead of showing part 3, it instead removes part 2 and goes back to just showing part 1. My issue is if you had 3 forms and you want to display each form in chronilogical order,(submit part 1 to show part 2, submit part 2 to see part 3) then how can I achieve this is my question. Am I ok to show my page structure in php fiddle for you to see structure of code?

Comment: @user1723760 I thought my code worked as you said in your comment? If you run the code without edit it, does it work ok?

Comment: And it would indeed be easier to help you if i can see your whole code, and be able to make changes and watch the results in realtime =)

Comment: Here is php fiddle which shows whole page: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cbx-6mi  . To see how the page is working on browser, click on this link: [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text23.php). You will be able to see problem, after second submit button `View Assessment Details`

Comment: @user1723760 Add "<input type='hidden' name='moduleSubmit' value='".$_POST['modules']."'>" at line 116, you need to include the old data in the new form, or it will think you haven't given that data.

Comment: I am getting some errors when I included the hidden input which I am not sure if I need an isset somewhere for `modules` but I will post errors in update and line number, php fiddle in comment will be updated. Have a look in 10 mins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22831/discussion-between-zombiespy-and-user1723760)

Comment: Application: [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php)......  PHP FIDDLE: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cbx-6mi

Comment: @user1723760 How is it going?

Comment: Have you still got your code you told me to change which I was reluctant to change to which was to make the code nicer, I want to go back onto that code. Im really struggling